# Question about meaning of "per capita" in this context

Tags: word-meaning

> Did they cover the strip club per capita numbers? Those are staggering.
>
> No, just restaurants per capita.

I know **per capita" means **for each person" , but I have my doubts whether the sentences would still be meaningful after substituting the words.
Could you simplify the conversation, pkease.

Answer (score 1):

These sentences could be written as:

> Did they cover the number of strip clubs **for each person**? Those are staggering.
>
> No, just **the number of** restaurants for each person.